# Finding the kernel of a linear transformation between polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Find the kernel of the linear transformation of $T:P^4\rightarrow P^4 $ defined by
$$ T(p) = p'' -p'-p$$
Previously I had to prove this was a linear transformation, and was successful, but I am having trouble on finding the kernel. I was thinking about setting arbitrary values for the coefficients of the polynomial.  Is that the right direction to head?

Comment: Take the general polynomial $ax^3 +bx^2 + cx +d$, transform it, then set the resulting equation to zero. Note that you're not solving the polynomial itself just the coefficients.

Comment: What is $P^4$ supposed to denote? (It may be standard but it's not obvious from context.)

Comment: @Semiclassical polynomials of degree $3$ or less.

Comment: Isn't a notation like $P^4$ usually used for polynomials of degree 4 or less?

Comment: @aexl The text I used set $n$ to be the number of coefficients not the degree of the polynomial. This way $n$ is the dimension of the space.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying that, maybe you could mention this in the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

We  look for $ p\in P^4 $ such that

$$T(p)=0$$
but

$$\text{ degree  of } \; T(p)=\; \text{ degree of } p =0$$

$$\implies p=Ct=0$$

Answer (score 1):

All solutions to the differential equation
$$
p''-p'-p=0
$$
are combinations of exponentials (Solving the characteristic equation, you find what those are). None of them is a polynomial, except the trivial one. Therefore, the kernel is the zero polynomial and $T$ is injective.